# Is it possible to trigger the Alexa Test per url?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

In your Alexa skill is a section where you can test the program.
https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask/test/yourskill
There you can type in a question for your skill. Is it possible to do this with a link.
Like sending the link with the question text as a parameter?
In other words I want to catch the submit-function that is triggered with "Enter".

Background: for a university project we want to "hack" alexa to start an interaction.

Comment: are you trying to test the interaction? or are you trying to get a spoken response from alexa???